# Analysis of Integral of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

one more question today I've been thinking on...

Prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $0<a<b$, then $\int_{a}^{b} {f(t) \over t} dt$ $=$ $\int_{a}^{s} {f(t) \over a} dt$ for some $s \in [a,b]$.

Intuitively this seems clear. $f$ being continuous means that if we view the $f(t)/a$ integral from $a$ to $b$ as a limit of its integral from $a$ to $s$ as $s \to b$, then we should find some intermediate $s$ that "catches" the $f(t)/t$ integral as $s$ slides along the integral since $1/t\leq1/a$. Problem is I can't find a nice way to write it formally. Thoughts?

EDIT: I was able to prove the following:

If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and (WLOG) nonnegative, and $g$ is monotone decreasing and positive, then we have an $s$ in $[a,b]$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} fg = g(a)\int_{a}^{s} f$, which happens to be exactly the conditions we need on the problem above. I believe it should be true for arbitrary (even non constant) sign on $f$, and $g$ shouldn't have to be decreasing or positive, but it's something, and it solves the problem. Not to mention it is easy to prove with a simple application of IVT.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem works for this (if $f$ is nonnegative). Did the problem specify that $f$ is nonnegative?

Comment: Nope, I already tried to use that one.

Comment: Is $f$ nonnegative though?

Comment: Do you know "second mean value theorem for integration"? 1/t is nonnegative. That's enough.

Comment: No :) $f$ is just continuous

Comment: I hadn't seen that MVT, no. If you make $g(t) = 1/t$ your nonnegative function, I don't see how the result follows.

Comment: Here G(t)=1/t and $\phi(t)=f(t)$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_integration

Comment: Do you know how to prove that, or know of a good source that proves it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28619/question-on-second-mean-value-theorem-for-integration

Comment: I don't really understand that proof. Is there a proof that doesn't use measures? This is just a Riemann integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on this problem recently, too! In order to show it I think it helps first to prove the following:

> **Theorem**
>
> If $f$ is continuous and $g$ is integrable and non-negative, then there is some $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) \, dx = f(\xi)\int_{a}^{b} g(x) \, dx$$

This you can prove in the natural way you described (by thinking about the maximum and minimum of $f,$ I'll leave you the joy of doing that one!)

Now to your problem. We use integration by parts and the above theorem to proceed. Define $F = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ to write
$$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(t)}{t} dt = \left[\frac{F(t)}{t}\right]_{a}^{b} + \int_{a}^{b}\frac{F(t)}{t^{2}} dt = \frac{F(b)}{b} + F(\xi)\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt$$

for some $\xi \in [a,b]$ (by the above theorem). If you work this out, you get to an answer very similar to yours but a little different. I wonder, was your answer a conjecture or have you been asked to show this by a lecturer/book?

EDIT:
I think the conclusion should be
$$ \exists \xi \in [a,b]: \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) = g(a)\int_{a}^{\xi}f(x)\,dx + g(b) \int_{\xi}^{b} f(x)\,dx $$
and not simply
$$ \exists \xi \in [a,b]: \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) = g(a)\int_{a}^{\xi}f(x)\,dx$$
Otherwise we could choose, for example, $g(x) = x, f(x) = 1$ and $[a,b] = [0,1].$ Similar considerations lead you to conclude that $g$ must be either non-decreasing or non-increasing (but it doesn't matter for $f$). The integration by parts method outlined above for $g(t) = 1/t$ should work as a proof for any such $g$ with $g^{\prime}$ continuous.

Comment: I have also seen your theorem! And no, I saw a similar problem and wondered if this was true. Now I know it is! Still working out the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a complete proof: [Here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matngtb/Calculus/Fourier%20Series/Second%20Mean%20Value%20Theorem%20for%20Integrals.pdf). This is the 3rd situation. This proof doesn't involve measure theory.

Comment: Thanks! I assume you just take B=0?

Comment: Yes. Just take $B=0$.